# Cannot connect to Firebird

Tags: database

I'm not sure, if the question belongs here. How can I find out if an application tries to connect to Firebird? I could imagine using Wireshark, but is there an easier way?

Long story: I wrote an application which used to work, and now it fails with the message "unavailable database". This is no programming question, since I know the exact place where it happens and I'm perfectly sure, it's alright. Older binaries stopped working, too. Fresh Firebird installation didn't help, and Firebird itself works, too. I can connect to it using telnet, ISQL works. I tried to switch off the firewall.

### I see, I forgot some important details:

- it's XP64
- it's Firebird 2.5, but I had the same problem with 2.1
- both client and server run on localhost
- the client aborts immediately with the error "unavailable database"
- I can connect to FB using isql or other tools

I know, this looks like a problem of a newbie who can hardly switch his computer on. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

- Check `netstat -lpn` on which addresses the Firebird is listening to. Is your Firebird server running standalone or via inetd?
- Is telnet working from server where the application is running? Use THE SAME credentials.
- Run tcpdump with dst port  and try to connect from the application or telnet.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, I'm a poor user of windows. There's netstat, and I tried it, but it seems to be able only to show currently active connections. When my app tries to connect (or whatever it does), it ends instantly with the error. The credential are the default ones (no need for security here), both client and server run on localhost. There's no tcpdump.